# Java IllegalBlockSizeException for data longer than 512 bytes

Tags: java, encryption

I have written a little chat and messages are objects like

```
{type="message",sender="userA",content="plaintextmessage",recipient="userB"}
```

that are sent to the server who spread it to all enrolled users.  I want to encrypt the plaintextmessage-part that the message object looks like

```
{type="message",sender="userA",content="bHJg67&GghjGZuf/zdu=",recipient="userB"}
```

I have build my RSA keypair on both - server and client.

```
KeyPair keyPair = buildKeyPair();
PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
```

Then i encode the servers public key to a byte array and this array to a base64 encoded string and send it to the client.

```
byte[] encodedPublicKey = publicKey.getEncoded();
String b64PublicKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encodedPublicKey);
```

Both, client and server, have implemented the functions

```
public static byte[] encrypt(PublicKey othersPubKey, String message) throws Exception {       
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");  
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, othersPubKey);  
    return cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());        
}

public static byte[] decrypt(PrivateKey privateKey, byte [] encrypted) throws Exception {   
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");  
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);        
    return cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
}
```

When i try to encrypt a message on the client, send it to the server and decrypt it there i get the error

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 512 bytes
```

Does that means that this encryption method is nout suitable for my messages? I found [Java/JCE: Decrypting "long" message encrypted with RSA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295436/java-jce-decrypting-long-message-encrypted-with-rsa?rq=1). Is that my new goal?

Comment: Yeah, you don't use asymmetric encryption for encrypting generic data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is called a hybrid cryptosystem. Even then, you may want to understand about the Bleichenbacher attack, the use of authenticated encryption, how to gain trust in a public key etc.

So your goal is either to study the field in *much* more detail or to learn a lot less about deploying TLS 1.2 or 1.3. Because it takes a lot of details to implement transport mode security.

If you want to continue, at least take a look at RSA in OAEP mode and AES in GCM mode.

Comment: Its just for private use and i guess i wouldnt become a crypto professional, so YES i will continue. But should i contnue the assymetric way instead?

Comment: In that case the hybrid mode as also shown in the other answer: encrypt random AES key, encrypt data, send both. Then for decryption: decrypt AES key and then decrypt data. Just in case you didn't get it yet: getting it working != getting it secure.

Comment: i know but the people i am aware of are just neighbors and stuff so its ok to be just a little bit "securer" of them ;P thank you